# Google App Engine: include an image blob in html template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have problem getting images displayed in the html template. I managed to store an image into the datastore. However, I don't know how to send it to an html file (or using an URL to display the image?). Please help and many thanks. The following is my code:

### main.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7

    import webapp2
    import common
    from google.appengine.ext import db

    class Image(db.Model):
        filename = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        data = db.BlobProperty(required=True)
        mimetype = db.StringProperty(required=True)

    class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            common.render(self, 'test.html', {})

        def post(self):
            imgfile = self.request.POST['image']
            img = Image(filename=imgfile.filename, data=imgfile.value, mimetype=imgfile.type)
            img.put()
            common.render(self, 'test.html', {'imgkey': img.key().id()})

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ("/.*", Test)],
        debug=True)
```

---

### test.html:

```
    <htm>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <p></p>Upload image: </p>
    <form method="post" action="/test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="確定" />
    </form>
    {% if imgkey %}
      Display:<br />
      <img src="http://.../disp?key={{imgkey}}" /><br />
    {% endif %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class ImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, image_id):
        image = Image.get(image_id)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
        self.response.out.write(image.data)
```

Then in your mapping, you should a create an url for image handling e.g:

```
(r'/images/(.*)', ImageHandler)
```

In your HTML code you need to create the image tags as follows:

```
<img src="/images/{{img1.key}}" /><br />
<img src="/images/{{img2.key}}" /><br />
```

Comment: Thanks Hans. But I would like to render several images in an html page. The code would be: "render(self, 'test.html', {'img1': img1.key().id(), 'img2': img2.key().id(), ... })", and the html would be: "<img src="...{{img1}}..." /><br /><img src="...{{img2}}..." /><br /> ...

Comment: I have clarified this in my post.